# How to represent rotation of image as a change of intensity, rather than change of coordinates?

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, linear-algebra

Normally, the rotation of image is represented in terms of change of coordinates, but can we represent the rotation transformation as a function of input image pixel intensities and the angle by which its needs to be rotated?

Comment: you need to specify center of rotation as well. If you have center of rotation and angle that gives you a change in coordinates.

Comment: The question in the title does not match that in the body. Please fix that.

Answer (score 2):

If your idea is to obtain the pixel intensity at one place as a function of the initial intensity at the same place, i.e. a relation of the form

```
I'(x, y) = f(I(x, y), Θ)
```

the answer is a clear no.

The new intensity depends on the intensity at another point of the image and there is no relation between these. The correct functional relation is

```
I'(x, y) = I(X(x, y, Θ), Y(x, y, Θ))
```

where `X` and `Y` relate the coordinates before and after rotation.